# Handling keyboard shortcuts in C# software

Tags: c#, winforms

*Edit: I have added the revised code in an answer to this question.*

---

Currently, I handle the keyboard shortcuts of my applications in a single huge method that looks like this:

```
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        // Next issue (validate the fix)
        if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.Enter) || 
            keyData == (Keys.Shift | Keys.Enter))
        {
            mark_as_fixed();
            return true;
        }
        // Skip to next issue without validating or changing anything
        if (keyData == (Keys.Alt | Keys.Down))
        {
            next_issue();
        }
        // Previous issue
        if (keyData == (Keys.Alt | Keys.Up))
        {
            previous_issue();
            return true;
        }
        ... [130 lines of this]
```

It works perfectly, it isn't particularly hard to read or maintain, but having a method 130 lines long and constantly growing just feels wrong.

Also I may want to implement shortcut customization in the future, and there is no easy way to find out what keys are mapped to which method so it will have to be rewritten.

Since all non trivial applications have a gazillion shortcuts, I assume it's a solved problem, but I couldn't find a good explanation on how applications handle their shortcuts.

Comment: Seems to me the `[130 lines of this]` could be relevant to a fruitful peer review. Can't you include the whole method body?

Comment: I'm afraid this question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving complete working code. The stub code that you have posted is not reviewable in this form because it leaves us guessing at your intentions.  Code Review needs to look at concrete code in a real context. Please see [Why is hypothetical example code off-topic for CR?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1709/41243)

Comment: @Mat'sMug I added the closing of the method. There is no point in posting the full list of my program's user methods and shortcuts.

Comment: Is which UI framework are you using? WinForms? WPF?

Comment: @Phrancis Nothing hypothetical about this method. I use it in an actual program. There is no more context than what is given in this question: The user presses a shortcut key, this method catches it and calls the relevant method of the program. Not sure what a long list of all my program's methods would add to the question.

Comment: @Mat'sMug It's a Winform application.

Comment: Hello! Please don't make changes to the original post once it has been reviewed, as that invalidates the current answers. Please see our meta side on [performing iterative reviews](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765) for more information!

Comment: What does message refer to as you have used it as an argument.

Comment: @TolaniJaiye-Tikolo ProcessCmdKey() is an existing .Net method which receives a Windows message (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644927(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reusing Mat's Mug's idea of a base Command class: what about using a Dictionary for the mapping?

This way you separate the ideas of command and shortcut (probably losing the potential help of reflection for programmatically instantiate your commands), but you can easily let your users map commands as they need.

Comment: An `IDictionary<Keys,Action>` would be ideal and was my first idea, but I dismissed it when I realized some commands had more than one hotkey... although... I guess you could map the same action to two `Keys` and call it a day.

Comment: Awesome. IDictionary<Keys,Action> appears to be by far the easiest way to implement and maintain that feature.

Comment: To implement, yes. To maintain, no.

Comment: Certainly a Dictionary alone could lead to maintenance issues if the list of shortcuts grows too much.
Still, having a big data structure to which add entries as needed is more readable than a huge switch statement (or the if...else equivalent).
Probably using this in combination with a more OO solution like yours is the way.

Answer (score 15):

> *Also I may want to implement shortcut customization in the future, and there is no easy way to find out what keys are mapped to which method so it will have to be rewritten.*

Stop right here! Extract a class for each command (e.g. instead of a `mark_as_fixed` method, you'll have a `MarkAsFixedCommand` class). <s>If you're using WPF you can implement the `ICommand` interface and have</s> *nevermind, you're using WinForms*. Still, extract the command classes - WPF's `ICommand` is a really simple interface that merely exposes `bool CanExcute(object)` and `void Execute(object)` methods (you don't have to implement the `object` parameter if you don't need it) - by extracting your logic into command classes, you can prepare the ground for the day you redo your UI with WPF (which you should!).

> *there is no easy way to find out what keys are mapped to which method*

Make one! Have your command classes derive from an abstract `CommandBase` class that exposes a method for it:

```
public abstract bool IsShortcutKey(Keys keys);
```

Now every derived command class *has* to implement this `IsShortcutKey` method. The implementation for `MarkAsFixedCommand` could look like this:

```
public override bool IsShortcutKey(Keys keys)
{ 
    return keys == (Keys.Control | Keys.Enter)
        || keys == (Keys.Shift | Keys.Enter); 
}
```

A cleaner way would have been to expose some `Keys ShortcutKey { get; }` property getter, but that wouldn't play nice with multiple shortcuts for the same command.

Anyway now that each command implementation is responsible for is shortcut key logic, you can easily fetch the configuration and make that method return `true` when `keys` matches whatever `Keys` value you have in your config.

Then, whoever runs this `ProcessCmdKey` method simply needs to know about all available commands - take them as an `IEnumerable<CommandBase>` constructor parameter and let whoever is calling this constructor deal with providing it with the command instances (which you will acquire with some reflection code).

Now `ProcessCmdKey` can be as simple as this:

```
// assume only 1 command returns true for specified keyData value:
var command = _commands.SingleOrDefault(cmd => cmd.IsShortcutKey(keyData));
if (command != null && command.CanExecute())
{
    command.Execute();
    return true;
}

return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
```

---

PS - Method names should be `PascalCase`, not `lower_snake_case`.

Comment: I've thought to myself before how could I implement something like this into a class to keep it organized. I really like the `Keys keys = (Keys.Control | Keys.Enter);` trick. For some reason that thinking just flew right past me!  Doing something like this would over complicate any programs I write as I'm only dealing with ~3-10 function keys for operators to use. +1 from me though. That's slick.

Comment: That looks interesting. One thing I am not sure about is how you get all the relevant classes into "_commands"? Also, it involves creating a lot of small classes. Wouldn't that become hard to maintain over time?

Comment: How is having dedicated classes "hard to maintain"? I'd strongly recommend you start reading up on *inversion of control* and *dependency injection* - the commands get injected into the type as a dependency, there's nothing to maintain, no code needs to change anywhere when you implement a new command. A dictionary is useful for a few items, but needs to be populated, and the actions need to live *somewhere*. When you have 100 commands, you need an architecture, not a dictionary.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Maintainable is somewhat in the eye of the beholder, in this case me. I am far more comfortable with code I can understand at a glance. My limitation, to be sure, but at this point in my learning, a dictionary holding Keys and functions fits the bill. A solution like yours is something I would try in a learning project in my spare time to see how it goes. Not in code that I plan on maintaining on the short term.

Comment: @Sylverdrag the beautiful thing about commands is that they're easy to reuse. You can take the same action from a hot key, a menu, a right click context menu, on an event, etc.

Comment: @RubberDuck exactly. ***without having to implement the code in as many places*** being the key here ;-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug it doesn't take much effort to use commands in Winforms either. In fact, I've already done the hard work. https://github.com/ckuhn203/Rubberduck.Winforms/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @RubberDuck yep.... you're telling someone that's running WPF-compatible `ICommand` implementations off a COM `CommandBar`, enabling/disabling the associated `CommandBarControl` per each command's `CanExecute` return value (and then reusing them in WPF context menus too) ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I use your method also except I would like to suggest using a `case` statement instead for readability.

I'm still a rookie programmer with less than a year of experience, so there could be better methods than this.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) 
    {
        switch (keyData)
        {
            case Keys.F1: 
                //Stuff
                return true;
            case Keys.F2:
                //Stuff
                return true;
            case Keys.Alt | Keys.Down:
                //Stuff
                return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

Also don't forget your `return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);` So you aren't disabling all other keys not specified.

Comment: In addition you could make the routines like `mark_as_fixed` return true. This would make the cases one-liners: `case Keys.F1:  return mark_as_fixed();`

Comment: I thought about using a switch, it would save a few lines but really, not much of a difference. It's still a long list of unmapped shortcuts. I am not concerned by how long it is just because it takes space, but because I think there has to be a better way to organize a program shortcuts, with some kind of mapping that would allow to the user to customize the shortcuts, find the current shortcuts for various features, print a list of shortcuts, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather use a more flexible design where you or the user can configure the shortcuts.

In this design each operation would be an `ICommand` with two members:

```
public interface ICommand
{
    Keys Keys { get; }
    void Execute();
}
```

An abstract `CommandBase` class would implement the `Keys` property:

```
public abstract class CommandBase : ICommand
{
    protected CommandBase(Keys keys) { Keys = keys; }
    public Keys Keys { get; }
    public abstract void Execute();
}
```

and concrete types the `Execute` method:

```
public class LoadReportCommand : CommandBase
{
    public LoadReportCommand(Keys keys) : base(keys) { }
    public override void Execute() { }
}
public class MarkAsFixedCommand : CommandBase
{
    public MarkAsFixedCommand(Keys keys) : base(keys) { }
    public override void Execute() { }
}
```

I would then make the shortcuts configurable via the app.config or any other configuration. The key would be the command name and the the value the keys:

```
private static IEnumerable<ICommand> _commands;

void Main()
{
    // this would come from a configuration
    var commandShortCuts = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        ["LoadReport"] = "Control+O",
        ["MarkAsFixed"] = "Shift+Enter",
    };

    // get all commands in this assembly
    var commandTypes =
        Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
        .GetTypes()
        .Where(t => t.BaseType == typeof(CommandBase))
        .ToList();

    // initialize commands and their shortcuts
    _commands = commandShortCuts.Select(x =>
    {
        var keys = x.Value.Split('+').Aggregate(
            Keys.None, 
            (result, next) => 
                result |= (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), next));
        var commandType = commandTypes.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Name.Equals(x.Key + "Command"));
        return (ICommand)Activator.CreateInstance(commandType, keys);
    })
    .ToList();
}
```

Then you could execute a command like this:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    var command = _commands.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Keys == keyData);
    command?.Execute();
}
```

Comment: Ooops, I now see that I've actaully implemented @Mat'sMug answer. Sorry? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have now, based on Mat's and Bel8z' answers:

```
Dictionary<Keys, Func<Keys, bool>> dic_shortcut_mngr = new Dictionary<Keys, Func<Keys, bool>>();
private void init_shortcuts()
{
    //Files
    dic_shortcut_mngr.Add((Keys.Control | Keys.O), open);
    dic_shortcut_mngr.Add((Keys.Control | Keys.L), load_report);
    // Operations
    dic_shortcut_mngr.Add((Keys.Control | Keys.Enter), mark_as_fixed);
    dic_shortcut_mngr.Add((Keys.Shift | Keys.Enter), mark_as_fixed);
    dic_shortcut_mngr.Add((Keys.Alt | Keys.Down), next_issue);
    dic_shortcut_mngr.Add((Keys.Alt | Keys.Up), previous_issue);
    dic_shortcut_mngr.Add((Keys.Insert), copy);
    //Copy items
    dic_shortcut_mngr.Add((Keys.Control | Keys.NumPad0), copy_item);
    dic_shortcut_mngr.Add((Keys.Control | Keys.NumPad1), copy_item);
    dic_shortcut_mngr.Add((Keys.Control | Keys.NumPad2), copy_item);
    ...
}

protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (dic_shortcut_mngr.ContainsKey(keyData))
    {
        return dic_shortcut_mngr[keyData].Invoke(keyData);
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
private bool copy_item(Keys key)
{
    //NumKeys start at index 96. Removing 96 gets the numkey's value 
    int i = (int)key - 96;
    if (dgv.Rows.Count > i && dgv.Rows[i].Cells["item"] != null)
    {
        string item = dgv.Rows[i].Cells["item"].Value.ToString();
        Clipboard.SetText(item);
        rtb_fix_target.Paste();
    }
    return true;
}
```

I decided to use `Func<Keys, bool>` instead of `Action` to be able to return "true" and pass on the keydata to the methods (which is useful handling the numpad shortcuts as they define the item to be copied)

Comment: Your naming convention is still very weird.

Comment: @t3chb0t I work alone and I have opted for lower snake case everywhere. Keeps things very simple, fairly readable and neatly differentiates my code from 3rd party code. Are there benefits to a more conventional (and more complex) .NET naming convention that would apply to a single developer?

Comment: You are never a single developer. You show other devs your code to review it or someone will need to take care of your code in the future and they won't be happy seeing this as we aren't ;-) There is a convention in C# that uses the underscore-snake casing for event handlers. Everytime I see `some_name` I need to stop and think: _is this an event handler?_

Comment: @t3chb0t  I can hardly see myself changing my naming conventions just because I might post a few lines here every once in a while. If it comes to selling and turning over my code to someone else, Resharper can change the naming convention in a jiffy. I am always keen to improve, but there has to be some benefit beyond "that's how we do it" (whoever is "we" anyway?). As for the confusion with event handlers, if I am not mistaken, .NET event handlers are a mix of camelCase, snake_case and PascalCase: "toolStripButton_DoubleClick()".